# else without if when trying to create register system

Tags: java, if-statement

When trying to run the following code, it produces an else without if error.

```
public void registerStudent(int register) {
    {
        if (register >= 100)
            System.out.println("The maximum number of students allowed on this course is 100.");      
    }
    else 
    {
        register = register + 1;
        System.out.println("You have been registered on the course.");
    }
}
```

Comment: register = register + 1; can be register += 1;

Comment: `register = register + 1;` can also be `register++;`

Comment: This question appears to be spam

Comment: This question changed completely on the last edit and has no useful content whatsoever.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have an extra `{` at the beginning of your method, and you forgot a `{` after the if condition.

change

```
{
if (register >= 100)

    System.out.println("The maximum number of students allowed on this course is 100.");
}
```

to

```
if (register >= 100)
{
    System.out.println("The maximum number of students allowed on this course is 100.");
}
```

Your current if condition is enclosed in its own block, and is completely separated from the else clause.

Comment: Nine upvotes for moving a misplaced curly brace?  You must have a great fan club :-)

Comment: @ajb I've learned there is a very weak relation between the number of upvotes and the complexity of the question/answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your feeling that `register = register + 1` is incorrect, is the right feeling.  In this code (with the syntax error corrected):

```
public void registerStudent(int register) {
    if (register >= 100)
    {   
        System.out.println("The maximum number of students allowed on this course is 100.");
    }
    else 
    {
        register = register + 1;
        System.out.println("You have been registered on the course.");
    }
}
```

When another method calls `registerStudent(nnn)`, the program will make a *copy* of whatever the value of `nnn` is.  Your method will have a local variable named `register` whose value starts out as the value of `nnn`.  When you say `register = register + 1`, that local variable is increased by 1.  But then the method returns, and the local variable goes away, so all the hard work of adding 1 to the variable becomes meaningless.

You probably want `register` to be a field in some object.  Most likely, if `registerStudent` is a method in some class (like a `StudentRegistry` class), then `register` should be a private field in the class, and `registerStudent` shouldn't have any parameters:

```
private int registrySize;

public void registerStudent() {
    if (registrySize >= 100)
    {   
        System.out.println("The maximum number of students allowed on this course is 100.");
    }
    else 
    {
        registrySize = registrySize + 1;
        System.out.println("You have been registered on the course.");
    }
}
```

This causes a field in an object to be modified instead of a local variable, and the new value will still be there after the method returns.

**MORE:** If the "registry size" or "student number" field is in an object of another class, then the best approach would be to pass that object (actually a reference to it) as a parameter.

```
public void registerStudent(RegistryClass registry) {
    if (registry.getStudentNo() >= 100) {
    {   
        System.out.println("The maximum number of students allowed on this course is 100.");
    }
    else 
    {
        registry.incrementStudentNo();
        System.out.println("You have been registered on the course.");
    }
}
```

This assumes `RegistryClass` has methods to retrieve and increment the current number of students.  (You could make the "number of students" a `public int` member in `RegistryClass`, but providing "getter" and "setter" methods is generally much better.)

Comment: @jayyy I added more, hope that helps.  I'm assuming your "other class" is named `RegistryClass`; change it to whatever the actual class name is.

Comment: @jayyy I was assuming you could change `Course` to add an `incrementStudentNo` method.  Is `Course` your own class, or is it provided by someone else?  If you can't change `Course` (heh, heh), what methods does it provide that you could use?  Or does it have a `public int` field that you can modify?

Comment: @jayyy Does it have `setStudentNos`?  In that case, `course.setStudentNos(course.getStudentNos()+1)` will add one to the value.  If not, perhaps edit your original question and show us what `Course` looks like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63967/discussion-between-jayyy-and-ajb).